# User does not have permission to perform this action. ? what was the problem?

Tags: asp.net, windows, vb.net, hosting, web-hosting

When i upload my site in aspspider.com then it shows the following message..what was the problem in that...i m totally confused ..

I use default dataase of asp.net namely ASPNETDB.MDF

```
Server Error in '/dobriyal' Application.

User does not have permission to perform this action.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: User does not have permission to perform this action.

Source Error: 


Line 7:          Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT Password FROM a1_admins WHERE EmployeeId =" & TextBox1.Text & " And Email = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'", SQLData)
Line 8:  
Line 9:          SQLData.Open()
Line 10:         Dim dtrReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
Line 11:         If dtrReader.HasRows Then

Source File: C:\MemberSites\MemberSites_AspSpider_Org\dobriyal\webroot\admin\forgot_password.aspx.vb    Line: 9 

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): User does not have permission to perform this action.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +1019
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   admin_forgot_password.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\MemberSites\MemberSites_AspSpider_Org\dobriyal\webroot\admin\forgot_password.aspx.vb:9
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like whatever user your using to connect to the database to doesn't have select permissions on that table.

Use [grant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187965%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) to fix that.

Comment: @user522211 you can't do that in web.config only in the database itself. If you have username and password of other database user that does have permissions, put it in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

It's your database that has not allowed the user permission. In your connection string, what user is it? Use '[Grant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)' to give this SQL user the necessary access. Probably needs to be able to SELECT from the necessary tables.